# Convert String from AS400 to Java

Tags: java, linux, ibm-midrange, jt400

To communicate with `as400` I use a java web service with the `jt400` library, this web service is running under Linux.
The text result after calling as400 program contains accented character like `é à è`… but in my `xhtml` page the text isn't displayed correctly, for example `é` is replaced by `{`.

The `as400` is configured like this: `ccsid : 65535` and `encoding : 297`.
When the same web service run under windows, I can display correctly accented characters
Thank for help.

Comment: Q: Do you have the IBM Toolbox for Java: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r1/ic2924/index.htm?info/rzahh/javadoc/ccsidList.html?

Comment: I think by default it's going to use ISO-8859-1 encoding instead of UTF-8 (hence, not being able to represent some chars).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have ran in to [Mojibake](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) caused by interpreting bytes of text in the incorrect encoding. You mention `é` being replaced by `{`; the code point for `é` in [CCSID 297](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC_297) is `0xC0` which in [CCSID 37](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC_037) is `{`, so this makes sense.

I'm not sure where the data is coming from, but if you're using [AS400Text](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzahh/com/ibm/as400/access/AS400Text.html) to convert the data in to a Java String object, you'll need to specify the correct CCSID or it will pick a CCSID based on the current locale. You can either specify the CCSID from [AS400.getCcsid](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzahh/com/ibm/as400/access/AS400.html#getCcsid()) or the associated encoding string value from  [AS400.getJobCCSIDEncoding](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzahh/com/ibm/as400/access/AS400.html#getJobCCSIDEncoding()).